# XJC (custom HelloWorld) plugin not loaded

Tags: java, xjc

I have created a jar with a *Hello World* xjc plugin.

```
package org.czentral.xjc;
...

public class HelloWorldPlugin extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public String getOptionName() {
        return "Xhello-world";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return " -Xhello-world: Hello World plugin.";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(Outline otln, Options optns, ErrorHandler eh) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Hello World running.");
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have added a `META-INF/sevices/com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin` file with a single line telling:

```
org.czentral.xjc.HelloWorldPlugin
```

After this I expected my *usage* line to show up in the help output for:

```
xjc -classpath XJC-Hello.jar -extension
```

Copying the jar to jdk/jre/lib/ext folder yields no results either. Neither does adding the jar to CLASSPATH environment.

I have checked the `jaxb-ri` sources and the plugins implemented in the `/com/sun/tools/xjc/addon/*` folder do not really show any additional requirements a plugin has to satisfy.